# To get a small strip near the boundary of a smooth bounded domain

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative function such that $lim_{x\to x_0}u(x)=0$ for every $x_0\in\partial\Omega$ where $x\in\Omega$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $u\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ in $A_{\delta}=\{x\in\overline{\Omega}:dist(x,\partial\Omega)<\delta\}$. Can you please explain whether this is true or not. Please give an explanation. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Apparently you mean $\Omega$ rather than $\overline{\Omega}$ in the definition of $A_\delta$, as otherwise $u$ is not defined in all of it. Apart from that, the answer is yes, because $\partial\Omega$ is compact.

Comment: AS @TaneliHuuskonen said, use compactness of the boundary. For each boundary point $x$ there is a corresponding $\delta_x$ just by definition of the limit. Then the family of balls $B(x,\delta_x)$ covers the boundary, so extract a finite subcover, and complete the proof from here.

Comment: the function $u\leq 0$ on $\partial\Omega$ in the sense that for every $\epsilon>0$, $(u-\epsilon)^+\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)$, the standard Sobolev space and $u\geq 0$ on $\partial\Omega$ if $-u\leq 0$ on $\partial\Omega$. We say that $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ if $u\leq 0$ and $u\geq 0$ on $\partial\Omega$. Then can we get such $A_\delta$? Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: Can You explain how to extract the required $\delta$ from the finite family of subcover $B(x,\delta_x)$? Here the space dimension is $N\geq 2$ . Thanks in advance.